# java print arraylist element on screen but wait user press enter to print next one

Tags: java, io, user-input

I am writing a java program and try to print a arraylist element on screen. But I wanted to print one at a time, and wait user press Enter to print the next one. How should I modify the below code ?

```
import java.util.*

public class printonscreen{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        test.add(0);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(2);
        test.add(4);
        for(int i=0; i<test.size(); i++){
             System.out.print(test.get(i));

             // wait user press enter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmirAfghani: That's not going to work well. Original poster, instead, look into: [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Why wouldn't that work @HovercraftFullOfEels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would you normally do to wait for user input? If you don't know, It's a `Scanner`. The `nextLine()` (instance) method of the `Scanner` class can temporily block the running thread and wait for user input in the console.

So you should do something like this:

```
import java.util.*

public class printonscreen{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        test.add(0);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(2);
        test.add(4);
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<test.size(); i++){
             System.out.print(test.get(i));

             // wait user press enter
             s.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

See the `nextLine()` part?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JOptionPane like this:

```
import java.util.*

public class printonscreen{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        test.add(0);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(2);
        test.add(4);
        for(int i=0; i<test.size(); i++){
             System.out.print(test.get(i));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press Ok to continue", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the image in the box by change the attribute `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE`

there are five styles:

- ERROR_MESSAGE
- INFORMATION_MESSAGE
- WARNING_MESSAGE
- QUESTION_MESSAGE
- PLAIN_MESSAGE

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
System.in.read()
```

after the print line in your for loop

Answer (score 1):

See if this works :

```
import java.util.*;

public class printonscreen{

public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    test.add(0);
    test.add(1);
    test.add(2);
    test.add(4);
    for(int i:test ){
         System.out.print(i);

         sc.nextLine(); // wait user to press enter



    }
}
```